# javascript/typescript: find index value of an input group

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code

```
<div id="select_group">          
                <div id=“attr_1”>
                <label>One</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id=“1” (change)="NextAttr($event)” name="selectProd">
                            <option value="0">Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor = "let prod of selectProduct.values" value="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</option>                    
                      </select>
                </div> 
               <div id=“attr_2”>
                <label>One</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id=“2” (change)="NextAttr($event)” name="selectProd">
                            <option value="0">Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor = "let prod of selectProduct.values" value="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</option>                    
                      </select>
                </div> 
             <div id=“attr_3”>
                <label>One</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id=“3” (change)="NextAttr($event)” name="selectProd">
                            <option value="0">Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor = "let prod of selectProduct.values" value="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</option>                    
                      </select>
                </div> 
       </div>

atrCount:number = 1;   
 selectNextAttr(id,attr){            
    var atr  = document.getElementById("attr_"+attr) as HTMLSelectElement; 
    var attrDetails = document.getElementById(attr) as HTMLSelectElement;          
    var index = atr.ATTRIBUTE_NODE; 
    let attr_count = this.atrCount++;
    let attribute = attrDetails.id; //eg: color
    let attribute_val = attrDetails.value;       
    let queryString:Array<any> =[];        
    let q = id + "&attribute_set_count=" + attr_count + "&attribute"+attr_count+"="+attribute+"&attribute"+attr_count+"_value="+attribute_val;
    queryString.push(q);        
    this.selNextAttr(q);

 }
```

Dynamic select box:

```
<div id="attr_{{selectProduct.attribute}}">
            <label>{{selectProduct.attribute | uppercase}}</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="{{selectProduct.attribute}}" (change)="selectNextAttr(selectProduct.product_id, selectProduct.attribute)" name="selectProd">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option *ngFor = "let prod of selectProduct.values" value="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</option>                    
                  </select>
            </div>
```

How do I get the index value of these select boxes using javascript or typescript? For example; if an items from the first select box is chosen I would like to return an index of 1. Thanks for the help.

A

Comment: Where do you want to get it? Inside `NextAttr` function? If so then `event.target.id`

Comment: you can add another argument to `NextAttr`. Like `NextAttr($event, 1)`. And hardcode them for each `select` as per their `id`s

Comment: I would like to capture it in the function NextAttr. The select boxes are going be be added dynamically; each with an unique div id. Is there a way I can reference the div ID and get the index value for that select box? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would add them dynamically and what `id` will you be settings?

Comment: Sure, updated my question to show those details. The attribute value will be unique for each select box.

Comment: So, there's a lot wrong here. You're using "curly quotes" to surround attribute values, which is not allowed in HTML. The element returned by use "attr_" + attr would be the `div`, not the `select`, so casting it as an `HTMLSelectElement` is probably a bad idea. It seems like you're already passing the "index" into the ID of the `select`. If that's incorrect, you'd have to get a list of all of the `select`s, then find the chosen one in that list to determine the index.